# How do I programmatically disable BurstFilter and enable it with some parameters in log4j2?

Tags: java, log4j2

I am planning to use log4j2's `burstFilter` in my application for burst logging management. The idea is to have it disabled until the administrator really wants to use it (I am planning to give an option in the application GUI to take parameters from the user and activate `burstFilter` accordingly).

I studied its documentation and realized that it's just a config change inside the log4j2.xml file. This xml config will be bundled along with the application anyway and I will include the filter like this..

```
<Console name="console">
 <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %x %t %m%n"/>
 <filters>
  <Burst level="INFO" rate="16" maxBurst="100"/>
 </filters>
</Console>
```

Now, here `rate` and `maxBurst` fields are set to some values which is not what I expect by default. One solution I thought of to just not use `<filters>` tag by default and explicitly write  in the log4j2.xml once user sets these paramters in the GUI like below.

`<Burst level="INFO" rate="16" maxBurst="100"/>`

This feels like the  rookiest solution, so I was wondering if there is any default attribute which I can toggle to switch the filter ON or OFF.

Expectation:
Default log4j2.xml:

```
 <filters>
  <Burst Activated="False" rate="16" maxBurst="100"/>
 </filters>
```

If user wants to activate it:

```
 <filters>
  <Burst Activated="True" rate="16" maxBurst="100"/>
 </filters>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unless the filter provides a parameter to enable/disable it I don't know of any way to directly toggle it. However, you can implement a toggle if you use the [RoutingAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender) to switch from an appender with the filter to one without the filter. The disadvantage is, obviously, that you need to have 2 appenders configured which could lead to some duplication of the configuration data. (You could extract some things into common properties which are shared between the two)

Here is a simple example using the `ThresholdFilter` which demonstrates the above strategy:

First, the log4j2.xml configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <!-- 
        See how I defined a common property to hold the pattern since it is used
        in both appenders below.
     -->
    <Properties>
        <Property name="pattern">%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Property>
      </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleWithFilter" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}" />
            <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </Console>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}" />
        </Console>
        <Routing name="Routing">
            <Routes pattern="$${ctx:filterToggle}">
                <!-- This route is chosen if ThreadContext has value "ENABLE" for key filterToggle. -->
                <Route key="ENABLE" ref="ConsoleWithFilter" />
                <!-- This is the default route when no others match -->
                <Route ref = "Console"/>                
            </Routes>
        </Routing>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="Routing" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Next, some Java code to generate logs:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;

public class SomeClass {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //We start with no value in the ThreadContext for filterToggle
        //  this should cause all logs to appear in the console.

        if(log.isDebugEnabled())
            log.debug("This is some debug! (This should appear in console)");
        log.info("Here's some info! (This should appear in console)");
        log.error("Some error happened! (We will also see this in the console)");

        //Now we enable the filter by switching appenders
        ThreadContext.put("filterToggle", "ENABLE");

        log.info("This should not appear in the console");
        log.debug("This also should --not-- appear");
        log.fatal("This will appear since it's more specific than ERROR level.");
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the output of the above:

```
12:22:35.922 [main] DEBUG example.SomeClass - This is some debug! (This should appear in console)
12:22:35.923 [main] INFO  example.SomeClass - Here's some info! (This should appear in console)
12:22:35.923 [main] ERROR example.SomeClass - Some error happened! (We will also see this in the console)
12:22:35.924 [main] FATAL example.SomeClass - This will appear since it's more specific than ERROR level.
```

I hope this helps you!